# CollectionViewController not seeing properties on the DetailViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, segue

I'm a novice and I'm trying to understand why my CollectionViewController is not seeing properties on the DetailViewController...any tips or insight would be appreciated. Code below...for my detailViewController.h and also my CollectionViewController.m, respectively.

```
//  DetailViewController.h
//  RecipePhoto
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *recipeImageView;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *recipeImageName;
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;

@end


#import "RecipeCollectionViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h".

@interface RecipeCollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *recipeImages;
}
@end

@implementation RecipeCollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    recipeImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"creme_brelee.jpg", @"egg_benedict.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg", @"green_tea.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", @"hamburger.jpg", @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg", @"starbucks_coffee.jpg", @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg", @"vegetable_curry.jpg", @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg", nil];
   }


 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipePhoto"]) {
 NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

      // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];

  // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     DetailViewController.recipeImageName = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 }
 }

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    //return arrayName.count;
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return recipeImages.count;
}
//provides the data for the collection view cells
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use  `recipeImageName` as a class property in `prepareForSegue`:

```
DetailViewController.recipeImageName = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

should be

```
detailViewController.recipeImageName = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Pay close attention to the capitalisation of the first letter. `DetailViewController` is the class; `detailViewController` is the local variable.

Comment: @AngieLinton, when a correct answer is provided, it's appropriate to mark the answer correct by checking the little green checkbox at the upper left part of the answer.  Glad the site helped you, but please learn to use it politely.  (Joe C is also correct that the question didn't provide evidence of debugging on your part)

Comment: @danh Thank you for telling me.  That was my first question, I didn't realize that I'd missed that step.   Cheers!